# Change <li> to <span>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change that:

```
<ul id="menu-footer-menue" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101">
        <a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/ueber-uns/" data-slimstat="5">Über uns</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100">
        <a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/impressum/" data-slimstat="5">Impressum</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99">
        <a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/datenschutz/" data-slimstat="5">Datenschutz</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To that:

```
<ul id="menu-footer-menue" class="menu">
    <span id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101">
        <a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/ueber-uns/" data-slimstat="5">Über uns</a>
    </span>
    <span id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100">
       <a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/impressum/" data-slimstat="5">Impressum</a>
    </span>
    <span id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99">
        <a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/datenschutz/" data-slimstat="5">Datenschutz</a>
    </span>
</ul>
```

On this page.

I already tried this:

```
var html = [];
var list = jQuery('#menu-footer-menue');

html.push('<div>');
jQuery(list.find('li').each(function() {
    html.push('<span>' + jQuery(this).text() + '</span>');
}));
html.push('</div>');
jQuery(list.replaceWith(html.join('')));
```

But sadly, it doens't work. Also I have to use `jQuery` instant of `$` because I am not allowed to install jQuery on this site for whatevery reason...

My question now is, how can I get the 3 points in one line?
My idea is to do that with jQuery changing `<li>` tp `<span>`. But as mentioned, it doesn't work... Where is there issue and how can I fix that or is there another/better way to do that?

Kind Regards

Comment: Just curious what the point is of this - `li` is better as it is semantically correct within `ul`. Is there some benefit to going through all this work to change them?

Comment: Why don't you just surround the li with a span?

Comment: What you're asking for is invalid HTML, and the browser will probably try to fix your mistake by modifying the HTML

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You said that it "doesn't work." What does it do? Does it change `ul` to `span` but the layout isn't the way you want it? Or does it fail to change `ul` to `span`? Either way, chazsolo is right, to change the layout you shouldn't be changing the semantic `li` elements to something else. Instead you could use CSS to change how the `li` elements are rendered.

Comment: Simple CSS: `#menu-footer-menue li {display:inline-block}`

Answer (score 4):

> ***My question now is, how can I get the 3 points in one line? My idea is to do that with jQuery changing `<li>` to `<span>`. But as mentioned, it doesn't work... Where is there issue and how can I fix that or is there another/better way to do that?***

Simple CSS no jQuery needed, and it's valid HTML. The reason why a `<span>` doesn't work is because it doesn't belong within an unordered list `<ul>`. List items `<li>` belong in an `<ul>`.

I've added demo 2 which is a way you can accomplish the same thing with jQuery, although it's totally overkill.

### Demo 1 - CSS

```css
#menu-footer-menue li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-footer-menue" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/ueber-uns/" data-slimstat="5">Über uns</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/impressum/" data-slimstat="5">Impressum</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/datenschutz/" data-slimstat="5">Datenschutz</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Demo 2 - jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu-footer-menue li').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu-footer-menue" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/ueber-uns/" data-slimstat="5">Über uns</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/impressum/" data-slimstat="5">Impressum</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/datenschutz/" data-slimstat="5">Datenschutz</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-footer-menue" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/ueber-uns/" data-slimstat="5">Über uns</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/impressum/" data-slimstat="5">Impressum</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://www.7tagetherapie.de/datenschutz/" data-slimstat="5">Datenschutz</a></li>
</ul>
```